# Is it possible to enter single bytes in C through terminal?

Tags: python, c

I have a fragment of code where something like this happens:

```c
char buf_path[0x100];
*len = fs->read(0, buf_path, 0x1000);
```

What I want to do is to enter two `NULL` bytes (`0x00`), two `\n` bytes (`0x0a`), then "`stackoverflow is wonderful`", then two `\t` bytes, then `\00`.

However, I have never seen that this is possible through a terminal and I have to enter `U` if I mean `0x55`, `2` if I mean `0x32` (all ASCII), so that for `0x00` I find nothing. Is it possible to enter bytes one by one for `read()`, like in Python with `b''`?

Thanks.

Comment: You can enter a null byte with Control-@

Comment: Control-@ opens a new tab in my coding editor and steals focus from my terminal. In particular, we have Linux 64bit + VSCode.

Comment: I'm talking about a regular terminal emulator. If you have hotkeys stealing some keystrokes, you need to disable them.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like: `echo "\0\0\n\nStackoverflow is Wonderful\t\t\0\0"`

Comment: @Barmar, well, this is the thing. "Something" works in the terminal, but I have no ability to test what. In a debugger and the code editor I could enter that and then check it. In a terminal I can only believe you that the `^@` resolves to `NULL`.

Comment: @Brandon, works in terminal, but not in the interactive mode, where your chars are stored as entered into the buffer...

Comment: There's nothing I can do about limitations of VS Code. Do your testing in a regular terminal window.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135313#issuecomment-951345541 Apparently in VSCode, it is `Control + Shift + 2`.

Comment: @Barmar, you saved my life! Thank you! Any ideas about `\n`?

Comment: ... or any other non-printable ASCII character, independently if through pure terminal emulator or VSCode (e.g. something wild like `196` decimal in ASCII table?

Comment: In VS Code's terminal the following works: `echo "\0\0\n\nstackoverflow is wonderful\t\t\0" | ./a.out`.

Comment: `\n` is just the enter key. But you should use `echo` like above to pipe the whole string